# Animation of points in Python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, graph

I have a given list with points (x, y), which changes during the course of the given function, for example:
`arr = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (5, 6), (8, 1)]`, which is the coordinates of the points (1, 2), (1, 3), (5, 6), (8, 1)

```py
for i in range (5):
     arr = function (arr) # different array
```

After each loop, I would like to draw a graph of coordinates with marked points, i.e. I want to create an animation from it. How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 1):

I would say do not plot them in any loop. Just accumulate all those values, pass it to whatever plotting library you are using (`matplotlib` does have animation support). Take a look here:  https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/animation_api.html

If your data is streaming, maybe use some time windows.